# 127v 60hz TV to 220v 50hz

Tags: power-supply, tv

[image]

Hi all 
I recently moved from Mexico to Portugal and brought some electronics I suspect they are multi voltage and multi frequency. 
But reading the label of a Sony TV I got into doubt if it is or not multi village/frequency.
Attached a photo of the label. Can I plug this TV straight on power outlet? 
My doubt is because in the center of the label says Energy Performance Verified 127v 60hz.
Thank you for any advice,
[image]

Hope it also applies for my Sharp one. Does it?
Thanks again

Comment: What does the fine manual say about it?

Comment: Please don't edit your original question to add another one.

Comment: Sorry for editing.

Comment: In the manual doesn't say anything about voltage. But, regarding the Sharp tv I took the risk and plug it on the 240v outlet. It is working well by the way. Just for anybody else looking for the same information.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion you can safely use this TV with 240 V, 50 Hz.

The 120 V 60 Hz is in it's own section and suggests that the FCC and UL US-listed ratings are for use at 120 V 60 Hz. Since FCC and UL US are only for the US where they use 120 V, this makes sense.

The UL Nom rating is broader and applies to 110 - 240 V 50/60 Hz.

Do note that in Portugal the oldfashioned analog TV broadcasts are in PAL format while in Mexico NTSC is used. If you're lucky the TV will handle that seamlessly for you. If you use a settop box (for digital TV) and connect over HDMI then that should work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I'll use it with settop box over HDMI and also with my laptop.

Comment: Tried on Sony and it worked perfectly. Thank you again for your support.

Comment: Sorry for the off topic question. I though it was an Electrical Engineering site as the logo on top left corner.

Comment: Sure but just being related to/about EE is not enough, the question also needs to fit the rules: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour and your question falls in the "how to use a device" category. But since in this case the label is confusing I answered anyway.

Comment: @AlexandrePerali Indeed the same applies to the Sharp device. Lots of US ratings, less for outside US. But it does say 120 - 240 V AC 50/60 Hz and that's the important line.